# How to achieve buttonX.setOnClickListener(this) in KOTLIN?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to bind "**this**" context to listener in kotlin

Comment: Exactly the exact same way as in Java

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin class you have to write the activity name with `@` annotation in order to get the `context` of the class.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, PicturesActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
}
```

or if you have override the `onclick` method just register the `onclick` method inside `onCreate`as

```
buttonX.onSetOnclickListener(this@ActivityName)
```

Comment: how to achieve this       " numberKeyboard.setListener(this)"

Comment: when ever you want to get the context of class by `this` in kotlin you have to write the name of the class attached with `this@`.. like `this@MainActivity`

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example on how to use the onClickListener in Kotlin

```
buttonX.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            //Code here ....
        })
```

Comment: how to achieve this [ numberKeyboard.setListener(this)